# Changing link format from Calendar widget

Tags: permalinks, calendar

I have the Calendar widget in the sidebar of my wordpress site. It currently links to each day's post using the date format such as "/2019/08/01/" instead of the permalink setting (post name). How can I change it to use the permalink setting? The post page displays differently when the link has only the date format and I don't want google indexing the posts twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calendar widget doesn't link to "each day's post". It's linking to an archive page that lists all posts made on that date. Hence the `/2019/08/01/` URL. If you click the post title (or "Continue Reading" or "Read More" link if there is one) you will be taken to the single post whose URL will match your settings.

If you've only ever made one post per day, then the date archive for a specific day will only show one post, but if you make more than that the date archive will show multiple posts on the same page. The purpose of the calendar widget is to provide links to these date archives. If you want one that links directly to individual posts, you'll need to find a 3rd-party alternative.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I didnt realize it was going to a daily list of posts. it explains why the page is differently formatted with the date on top. My site will only ever have one post per day at most. You don't have any good plugin recommendations. I want it basically be the same widget.. just with a link to the daily post instead.